# Is it a good practice to skip queries with empty conditions?

Tags: soql, governorlimits, bestpractice

I am wondering if it's a good practice to skip queries when there's nothing in 'where' clause, especially in triggers. Like:

```
if (idList.size() > 0)
    res = [select id from Case where id in :idList];
```

Doesn't it lead to some non-deterministic behaviors with hitting limits, depending on data? Is it good idea to save SOQLs like this, or it's better to have more or less the same number of SOQLs each time if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply said, when you are planning code paths through your code, you must consider the maximum possible governor limit usage that might occur. This is what I might call your deterministic limit. If that limit exceeds more than 50% of your transaction limits for queries or DML operations, you need to look at ways of cutting back, because administrative changes to the system might cause fatal governor limits to pop up (e.g. workflow field updates, roll up summaries, etc).

So, while your code is non-deterministic because of control structures, you should be able to determine if your code *could* reach governor limits, and if so, start working on reducing the number of queries and/or DML operations you have in your code. Unless you can prove that it's impossible for both branches of an if-else statement to occur, for example, include both of those queries in the total count against your governor limits to see if a problem might arise. Or, if you're calling a query inside a function, make sure the function isn't called in a loop. The list could go on and on, but you'll get a feel for what you should be watching out for as you continue to gain experience.

In small transactions, I *might* consider not guarding against any empty collections, for example, on a small Visualforce page where an empty list is hardly of consequence. In almost any trigger, however, you can bet I'll be finding ways of reducing usage as much as possible. I would always recommend erring on the side of caution and guarding against queries which will not return data.

Answer (score 3):

I would say yes, it is a good practice.

Unpredictability on whether you hit the limits or not should not be an issue. IMO, the best practice is to design your code in a way that you're *way below* execution limits. If running an extra query takes you over the limits, it probably means that you need to go back to the drawing board.

Additionally, skipping the query has a positive effect on performance. I would imagine there is still a delay involved in executing a query that returns no rows, and that could affect the user experience, if it happens in the context of a user taking an action (clicking a button, etc).

Comment: +1 Generally speaking, if you're at about 50% of your governor limit usage, you need to start cutting back, because workflow field updates can double this usage and cause fatal exceptions. So *way below* is definitely better than anything over 50% of your total query or DML usage. On the other hand, an impossible query on a table (such as an empty list of Ids) is *very* fast, because the optimizer realizes it's impossible. But you still get dinged with governor limits, so avoid those queries.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a good practice.

You ask "doesn't it lead to some non-deterministic behaviors with hitting limits, depending on data?" but I would revise the question, "doesn't it lead to **more** non-deterministic behaviors with hitting limits".

Your code is almost certainly non-deterministic about limits.

- Putting a query behind ANY `if` (other than `if(true)`) will cause non-deterministic limit use.
- Putting a query after any method call that may throw an exception you don't catch will cause non-deterministic limit use.
- Putting a query after a method call that may throw an exception you *do* catch (but don't then run that query anyway in your exception handler) will cause non-deterministic limit use.

So yes, it will cause more non-deterministic limit use. That's ok. Those numbers weren't 100% reliable anyway. And, in any case, if your code is so close to limit use that this single query margin could push it over the limit, you probably ought to work on much larger parts of your architecture.

And, it's **better for performance** to do so. In a traditional web environment, you wouldn't think twice about only making callouts to the database where warranted. The *addition* of limits to your environment shouldn't make your resource consumption go *up*.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has two parts

1. Doesn't it lead to some non-deterministic behaviors with hitting limits

If you really want to be more deterministic about your output I would rather suggest to do a benchmark with realistic data. When you do a Big O analysis these small scenarios like with or without conditional executions will always considered to executed (if statement here should always assumed to enter in)

2. Is it good idea to save SOQLs like this, or it's better to have more or less the same number

In my opinion I think its good to have these conditions in a environment with limitations. Because it not just saves our SOQL limits but also increases performance and unnecessary database locks on table

Answer (score 2):

There are two considerations here that I think you're missing:

- When querying against a collection, you should use `Set<Id>`, not `List<Id>`.

  - We can't see the type declaration in your code, but the naming convention you adopted implies you are using a `List`.
  - Using a `Set` will lower your heap consumption if you have duplicate values.
- If you are filtering on a nillable field, you should make sure your collection does not contain `null`.

  - This condition will cause a table scan, which will make your query non-selective if you have more than 100k records.
  - An added benefit of using `Set` instead of `List` is that you can just call `myIds.remove(null)`.

Comment: I just checked the Query Planning Tool, and apparently Id = NULL doesn't do a table scan (because Id cannot be nillable). I'll confirm this in my production org tomorrow. As an aside, using a Set may seem to make sense at first blush, but storage of new values is less efficient than lists as the size increases, and, unless you're processing a ton of records, the heap savings would be marginal (200 Ids in a List should only be about 40k of heap, which would be the same size of a Set of all unique IDs).

Comment: @sfdcfox Ah, I thought it was a lookup. If that were the filter, the table scan bit is still correct, right?

Comment: Definitely. Only non-nillable fields, like name and Id, are immune to the null-value-causes-table-scan rule.

Comment: @sfdcfox, thanks for the heads up! I didn't know non-nillable fields were exempt. Are there other pros/cons to `Set` vs `List`? I'd like to profile the heap considerations in more detail, but I'm curious what other arguments there are. I thought duplicate values used to throw but they definitely don't any more.

Answer (score 2):

In Salesforce, especially in layers of the application that are service-related or domain-related, avoiding SOQL calls when you know in advance there will be no rows returned is good practice as the 101 SOQL limit can readily be reached in complex transactions that invoke multiple sobject triggers or services. Hence, while you might not be the one affected by not testing for `if (myList.size() >0) {..do soql..}`, your colleagues or successors might run into an issue where they wished you had checked for empty lists.

A side note, testing for empty lists is not required when doing DML. The converse -- executing SOQL on where clause conditions with empty lists does consume SOQL.

```
if (mySobjList.size() > 0)  // this line is unnecessary
   insert mySobjList;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer is relevant to the question-- they're asking about skipping a query if you know it'll return no results.

Comment: @sfdcfox - edited